# Swagger @ApiParam require not working when null is passed

Tags: java, jackson, swagger

I have the following:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/some/path")
void createSomething(@ApiParam(required = true) @Valid final User user);
```

And `User` is something like

```
class User {
    @Valid
    @NotNull
    @NotBlank
    final String name;

    ...
}
```

I do get back 400 if I do `curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" /some/path -d '{"foo":"bar"}'`.

However, if I do not send any thing, then I do not get 400, i.e  `curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" /some/path` does not result in 400 (and later results in 500 cause the object `user` is now null.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your syntax looks OK, your test is valid ... and Swagger should certain support "required = true" for the @ApiParam annotation: http://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/v1.5.0/apidocs/io/swagger/annotations/ApiParam.html.  Q: What version of Swagger are you using?  Also: Q: What kind of app are you running?  A Java servlet?  Spring Boot?  "Something else"?

Comment: @paulsm4 1.5.12. Also running a Dropwizard app

Comment: @paulsm4 if i add `@NotNull` (so have `@ApiParam(required = true) @NotNull @Valid final User user`) then it works. but that seems odd because as you said `required` on `@ApiParam` should be doing that

Comment: I think Swagger is great.  And if you happened to be using Spring Boot, I might even try to reproduce the problem myself.  But it sounds like this might just be "one of those things" :( SUGGESTION: Check for "null" (and throw an exception) in your code.  I'd recommend this regardless.  It's not "redundant" - it's just a "smart thing to do:" ;)  And of course, you can always ask about it here, too: https://swagger.io/community/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swagger annotations do not perform any server-side validation of the input - they are only used to generate the swagger doc. Then you have to somehow create an user interface from the generated Swagger doc (for example by using Springfox swagger-ui if using Spring Boot https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger-ui). And finally, if the UI is generated correctly, the UI would perform the validation.

Since in the examples you were sending the requests using Curl, the swagger annotations do nothing (because you aren't sending the requests through Swagger UI) and thus you can send null value. In order to perform server-side validation you have to use other annotations.

Comment: The last time I used Swagger ("Swashbuckle", for .Net Core 2.x) the "generated Swagger doc" went hand-in-glove with the Swagger UI.  It handled C# Annotations (er... C# "Attributes" ;)) just fine.

Comment: yes it should, but it seems that the OP is not sending the requests through swagger UI and is using curl instead. Swagger annotations do not perform any server-side validation, they are only used for the generated swagger doc.

Comment: Yup - you're right.  I've only ever used EITHER curl OR Swagger (with Swagger UI), so I didn't realize that's what was happening.  Thank you :)  ALSO: I guess this a good example of why the OP should check for "user" in his code (and not rely exclusively on the annotation) ;)